# python split array into sub arrays of equivalent rank

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

**EDITED:**

I have an array of ***n*** sorted values.

I want to create ***m*** sub-arrays so that my best element goes into my first sub-array, my second element goes into my second sub array, etc, and my ***n+1-th*** best element goes into my first sub array.

If I have just two arrays its easy but if I want more than two sub-arrays I don't know how to do it.

for example if I have an initial array:

```
a = [50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 10, 9, 8]
```

And I want 3 sub-arrays I should get:

```
x1: [50, 35, 20, 8]
x2: [45, 30, 10]
x3: [40, 25, 9]
```

What's the most efficient/pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: `a.reshape(3,2).T`? It seems your method is equivalent to sorting by columns

Comment: You also can have any of this list singularly by doing something like `a[y::x]` with x the number of sublist, and y the number sublist index you're trying to get (starting from 0). For example if you want x2 from your example you do `a[1::2]` See the slice documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: I think I wrongly formulated the problem: please check my edit

Comment: All the answer bellow are for "2 sub-lists" when you start with "I want to create x sub-arrays". Maybe edit your question for it to be clear.

Comment: yes thanks just did that @T.Nel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR X SUBLISTS :**

One possibility would be to do :

```
def get_sublists(original_list, number_of_sub_list_wanted):
    sublists = list()
    for sub_list_count in range(number_of_sub_list_wanted): 
        sublists.append(original_list[sub_list_count::number_of_sub_list_wanted])
    return sublists
```

You can then unpack the sub-lists stored in `sublist`.

For example :

```
a = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
x1, x2 = get_sublists(a, 2)
```

will grant you the expected output.

This is the trivial solution. Their is probably something more pythonic in itertools or an other lib.

*If you don't understand how this code works , take a look at [the documentation of a slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).*

Comment: It looks great but does not work for the even sized arrays l = 10 that you want to split unevenly number_of_sub_list_wanted = 3. One element gets removed.

Comment: @S.Rucinski: You mean get_sublists(list(range(10)), 3))? It works. Theresult in [[0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]].

Answer (score 3):

#### For 2 arrays

```
x1, x2 = map(list, zip(*zip(*[iter(a)] * 2)))

print(x1, x2, sep='\n')

[5, 3, 1]
[4, 2, 0]
```

---

#### For 3 arrays

```
x1, x2, x3 = map(list, zip(*zip(*[iter(a)] * 3)))

print(x1, x2, x3, sep='\n')

[5, 2]
[4, 1]
[3, 0]
```

---

#### Why this works

1. `iter(a)` creates an iterator on the list `a`.  When you iterate through it, the elements get used up and eventually the iterator becomes exhausted.
2. `[iter(a)] * 2` creates a list that looks like this `i = iter(a); [i, i]`.  Notice that the **same** iterator shows up twice.  That means that when I take an element from the first `i`, I also take it from the second `i` because they point to the same iterator.
3. So! when I use `zip` on the unpacked list of the same iterator `zip(*[iter(a)] * 2)`, As I pair things up, I'm pulling from the same iterator and therefore naturally exhausting them in the order we want.
4. I then use another `zip` to transpose the results and then `map` with `list` to make them lists instead of tuples.

Comment: Yes.  Working on it (-:

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [5, 4, 3 ,2, 1, 0]

def get_original_val(original, x):
    return [original[index] for index in x]

def get_index(a):
    index_x1, index_x2 = [], []
    local_list = a if not len(a) % 2 else a + [0]
    for idx, x in enumerate(local_list):
        target = index_x2 if idx % 2 else index_x1
        target.append(idx)
    get_x1 = get_original_val(a, index_x1)
    get_x2 = get_original_val(a,  index_x2)
    return get_x1, get_x2

>>>x1, x2 = get_index(a)
>>>x1
[5, 3, 1]
>>>x2
[4, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I think the author asked for a more general solution, he wants to create x sub-arrays not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Below will give the desired answer,

```
a = [5, 4, 3 ,2, 1, 0]
a.sort(reverse=True)
x1 = []
x2 = []
for i in range(len(a)):
   x1.append(a[i]) if (i%2==0) else x2.append(a[i])
print x1, x2
```

Comment: I think the author asked for a more general solution, he wants to create x sub-arrays not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem. It divides a list of size *l* into *n* parts where *n-1* parts are of the equal size *l/n* and the last one n is of size *l/n + modulo of the division*.

```
def get_sublists(original_list, sublists_number):
        list_size = len(original_list)
        sublist_size_except_last = list_size//sublists_number
        last_sublist_size = list_size%sublists_number
        sublists = list()
        l_index = 0
        r_index = list_size-1
    
        for i in range(sublists_number):
            l_index = (i*sublist_size_except_last)
            r_index = ((i+1)*sublist_size_except_last)-1
            if i != sublists_number-1:
                sublists.append(text_list[l_index:r_index])
                print(l_index,r_index)
            else:
                r_index = r_index+last_sublist_size
                print(l_index,r_index)
                sublists.append(text_list[l_index:r_index])
    
        return sublists
```

For the list of strings of size 6538434. We get 5 sublists inside a one list sliced as follows:

```
  original_list[0:1307685]
  original_list[1307686:2615371]
  original_list[2615372:3923057]
  original_list[3923058:5230743]
  original_list[5230744:6538433]
```