# How to split a python array into different arrays based on a condition?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a python array like this:

```
array([[0.34201428, 0.46875536, 0.37900415, 0.4906195 ],
       [0.58203477, 0.35279346, 0.61418074, 0.37601328],
       [0.3388086 , 0.21167754, 0.37330517, 0.2436498 ],
       [0.57343255, 0.34535545, 0.62878576, 0.38982747]],dtype=float32)
```

I want to split the array into different clusters based on the zeroth column. The final output should be like this:
The first array as,

```
array([[0.34201428, 0.46875536, 0.37900415, 0.4906195 ],
       [0.3388086 , 0.21167754, 0.37330517, 0.2436498 ]])
```

And the second array as,

```
array([[0.58203477, 0.35279346, 0.61418074, 0.37601328],
       [0.57343255, 0.34535545, 0.62878576, 0.38982747]])
```

Can anyone help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python split array into sub arrays of equivalent rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442086/python-split-array-into-sub-arrays-of-equivalent-rank)

Comment: how should this splitting be done?  e.g. every other row.  where the first value is either side of 0.4.  or something else?

Comment: @Sam Mason in the above array 0.34 and 0.33 are nearby digits. similarly 0.58 and 0.57 are nearby digits. So the nearby digits in the main array should be splited as a new array

Comment: if you want to solve this generally then you should look into clustering algorithms. in this case just a simple `x[x[:,0] < 0.4]` is enough

Comment: If you know the clusters beforehand, use a conditioning like @SamMason proposed. Or have a look into clustering algorithms [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) for k-means or similar.

Comment: okay. clusters will not be known beforehand. every time i get a different array.

Comment: @Dorian note that k-means often isn't great for real world data.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html has a much more complete set of algorithms

Comment: @user34 then you're going to have to modify your question to explain what the criteria are (i.e. by editing the question rather than by adding comments).  what we've suggested so far more than solves the stated question

Comment: things that are relevant are: does the shape of the array change, does the number of clusters change, does the magnitude of the value change, is there any structure to the values in the data (i.e. are some columns correlated), etc

Comment: i think there is a pythonic way to do this. the logic is sort the array in ascending order based on zeroth column. then iterate through the zeroth column, compare i th value with i+1 th value. if the difference is less like we a set a threshold, then append that to a new list. when the difference is greater than the threshold append it to a different list similarly there with be n number of arrays. I don't know how to code this actually.

Comment: @SamMason k-means was only a suggestion.

Comment: @user34 if you don't want to use a clustering algorithm but want to write your own, edit the question (as suggested by @SamMason) with your algorithm and explain why it doesn't work. What you suggested though has several difficulties, e.g. are you comparing to the first value of a cluster, or the average? When and how are you computing the average of the cluster? When is the difference between 2 values large enough, does this depend also on the cluster size? etc.